# Orientating a pressure gauge

Tags: plumbing

I am installing a whole house water filter system to an existing loop and I am going to add 2 pressure gauges, one on the input and the other on the output side.
The loop pipe is 1" copper and I have 2 - 1" x 1" x 1/2" tees to which I will sweat a 1/2" x 1/4" C x FIP Copper Female NPT Adapter to accommodate the 1/4" gauge.

What is the trick to orientating the adapter before sweating to ensure that when I screw the gauge in that it is facing the correct direction when tightened. (I don't want to sweat the adaptor with the gauge screwed in)

Alan

Answer (score 3):

Imagine, if you will, that your whole plumbing system was threaded pipe. Which was common in many places for a certain time period...

With pipe fittings, you don't get a choice of orientation on threads. You just work with them as they come, and there is some practical leeway between "so loose it leaks" and "too tight" which is how you get things to align - proper use of decent pipe dope helps with this.

So, solder it in any which way. Tighten until the gauge faces the way you want, without leaks.

If you are super-fussy and like overly complex and expensive solutions, you can insert a union between the gauge and the rest of the system.

There are other options, such as using a compression fitting where the threads and the seal are separate functions, and the fitting does not turn as the nut is tightened. You could think of those as "fittings that act like a union."

Comment: In this particular case you can also thread the gauge and put a witness mark on the adapter.